# JavaScript: How to display time using a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I want to generate a custom time-formatted string via a switch statement where the date information is passed in an array.

For an array like this:

`let displaySumTimes = ['00', '00', '10']`

the expected output would be:

`10sec`

If a value in the array is greater than zero, then that should be included in the formatted string that is returned from my switch statement. Each non-zero value in the result also needs to have the corresponding time unit included with it in the formatted string result.

My current code looks like this:

```
 let displaySumTimes = ['00', '00', '10'];

 const formatTime = (time) => {
  const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');
  console.log([hour, minute, sec]);
  switch([hour, minute, sec]) {
    case hour > 0:
      return `${hour} h ${minute} min ${sec} sec`;
      break;
    case minute > 0:
      return `${minute} min ${sec} sec`;
      break;
    case minute < 1:
      return `${sec} sec`;
    default:
      // code block
  }  
}

 formatTime(displaySumTimes); //output 10sec

 let displaySumTimes1 = ['00', '10', '10'];


 formatTime(displaySumTimes1); //output 10min 10 sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could take a functional approach to this which would avoid the need for a switch statement.

For instance, you could dynamically build a list containing each part of the formatted string result (which is built based on the input values), and then `join()` that list a white-space character to compose a string with the required format:

```js
const formatTime = (time) => {
  const [h, m, s] = time;
  
  /* Dynamically build a temporary list containing each part of the formatted time depending
  on input values supplied*/
  return [].concat(
    h > 0 ? [`${ h }hr`] : [], 
    m > 0 ? [`${ m }min`] : [], 
    s > 0 ? [`${ s }sec`] : [])
  /* Join each part of the formatted time with a whitespace to achieve required formatting */
  .join(' ');
}

let displaySumTimes = ['00', '00', '10'];
let displaySumTimes1 = ['00', '10', '10'];

console.log(formatTime(displaySumTimes)); //output 10sec
console.log(formatTime(displaySumTimes1)); //output 10min 10 sec
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your switch syntax is incorrect. You are not destructuring there, you're making a switch on a new array (which you're creating there in the conditional). Why not simply refactor your cases to be ifs?

Also, you're using a string method (`split`) on an array. I don't see any strings with ":"s in your code. If you're going to be using an array which you know will look like that `['##', '##', '##']`, you could use ifs like this:

```
if (hour !== "00") return `${hour} h ${minute} min ${sec} sec`;
if (minute !== "00") return `${minute} min ${sec} sec`;
return `${sec} sec`;
```

Comment: You don't need the else there. If the first if statement is hit it will return and never hit the second one.